# Concatenating strings with special ending characters in C

Tags: c, string, character, concatenation

I'm learning C and attempting to implement a function

`char *es_cat(char *dst, char *src)`

that adds the string `src` to the end of `dst` but with a little twist: The strings are considered to end with a `'?'` character instead of the usual `'\0'`. The string that's created has to end with a `'?'` but the first string's `'?'` is ignored. Here's my attempt:

```
/* A simple function to determine the length of a string according to the
 * previously stated '?' constraint.
 */
unsigned int es_length(const char *s)
{
    const char *c = s;
    int amount = 0;
    while (*c != '?')
    {
        amount++;
        c++;
    }
    return amount;
}

char *es_cat(char *dst, char *src)
{
    int total = es_length(dst) + es_length(src) + 1; // + 1 for the last '?'
    char buffer[total]; 
    char *b = buffer;

    /* Copy the dst string. */
    while (*dst != '?')
    {
        *b = *dst;
        dst++;
        b++;
    }

    /* Concatenate the src string to dst. */
    while (*(src-1) != '?')
    {
        *b = *src;
        src++;
        b++;
    }
    printf("\n%s", buffer);
    return buffer;
}

int main(void)
{
    char cat_dst[] = "Hello ?"; // length according to es_length = 6
    char cat_src[] = "there! - Well hel?"; // length according to es_length = 17
    es_cat(cat_dst, cat_src);
    return 0;
}
```

Now, when I run I'm expecting an output: `Hello there! - Well hel?`. The string is basically the same but is followed by 3 characters of trash (to be precise, the output is now `Hello there! - Well hel?■@`). When I add or remove 3 characters from the cat_src char array, the trash characters are gone. Am I initializing the buffer wrongly or am I messing something with the pointers?

On the other hand, would it be possible to concatenate the string `dst` directly i.e. not creating a buffer?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: A printed c string needs to have a null terminating character to be a valid string.  If you are just moving it from one location to another, like in a packed message, you can get by without the terminator.  However in it's final form it should always have one.  You may want to verify you are understanding the assignment correctly, or perhaps that is the point.  Regardless, what you are seeing is to be expected without the null terminator.

Comment: You're pretty close.  Why are you subtracting 1 from src in your second while loop?  That's wrong because the first time in the loop you are indexing src[-1] which is out of bounds and undefined.  Also, you are returning the local array buffer which is also wrong ... but you're not using it.

Comment: Do not ignore warnings from your compiler about returning the address of a local variable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your functions use a different string terminator, but you are using still standard C functions to print out the string, and they require a null terminator char, so that, at the end you have to write a null terminator into the string.

```
char *es_cat(char *dst, char *src)
{
    int total = es_length(dst) + es_length(src) + 2; // + 1 for the last '?' and +1 for the '\0'
    char *buffer = (char*)malloc(total);
    char *b = buffer;

    if (buffer == NULL)
        return NULL;

    /* Copy the dst string. */
    while (*dst != '?')
    {
        *b = *dst;
        dst++;
        b++;
    }

    /* Concatenate the src string to dst. */
    while (*src != '?')
    {
        *b = *src;
        src++;
        b++;
    }
    *b = '?';
    b++;
    *b = '\0';
    printf("\n%s", buffer);
    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: Strings without a null terminator can be printed with `%.*s`, as in `printf("%.*s\n", NumberOfCharacters, String)` or `printf("%.*s\n", (int) (EndPointer - String), String);`.

Comment: You are returning the address of a local variable.